# Cpp: variable initialization syntax in a constructor declaration

Tags: c++

So I was editing a boilerplate cpp code for a coursera assignment and came across a rather unfamiliar syntax:

```
pl2_ranker::pl2_ranker(float c, float lambda) : c_{c}, lambda_{lambda} {}
```

Where `c_` and `lambda_` are both private float variables declared in class `pl2_ranker`.

Apparently, this constructor is assigning `c` to `c_` and `lambda` to `lambda_`, but as a non-cpp programmer, I've never encountered such a syntax before.

Could someone please let me know what this kind of syntax is called and what benefit it provides vs the regular variable assignment inside the function body?

Comment: It's a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: _and what benefit it provides vs the regular variable assignment inside the function body?_ You can initialise references and `const` member variables this way.

Comment: Also it is _initialization_, rather than _assignment_.

Comment: This is one of the many basic concepts of C++'s classes and objects. If you're unfamiliar with it, then you should find plenty of useful information to review [in your favorite C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. It's not practical to expect to learn it by reading random code and asking on a web site every time you don't understand something. Instead, you should start on Chapter 1, and continue reading one chapter at a time. That's the only way to learn it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, I'd be a fool not to expect that coming. But I'm not trying to learn how to code cpp here. This is a course on machine learning and it involves using a utility called meta written in cpp. So, as described in the course intro, general programming knowledge is enough to go through. I just got curious about this syntax and you guys have been more than helpful. Thank you all.